# How to Add a custom Email to Core_Email_template table

Tags: email-templates, core-config-data

What are the steps to adding a template to core_email_template. I created a new template in en_US/emails/...and created a system config field HOWEVER nothing is showing up in the table. What step am I missing? What are the FULL steps to doing this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to add templates is to go to System > Transactional Emails and create a new one by duplicating and existing template. You can call it whatever you like and modify as you wish.

Once saved, it should appear in the correct location for choosing based on the core template you used to create it.